# The TargetControlID is not valid / adding a control to a form in the asp.net code

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to add a control that I define in C# to my asp code, by doing this in my code:

```
<% this.Controls.Add(blah.GetControl()); %>
```

but I get the error: The TargetControlID of 'a8f08c40d0fab104ca20b1460ee1cbdd1e121' is not valid. The value cannot be null or empty.

Thats the controls GUID that I randomly generate in the get method.

Any explanation as to why I am getting it? Is what I am doing even allowed - putting that code above into my aspx file?

Edit: Additional code for the new ID problem:

```
.
.
    <div id="divDetailsContent" style="width:100%">
.
.
<% this.Controls.Add(blah.GetControl("divDetailsContent")); %>
.
.
public static blah GetControl(n)
{
.
.
blah.TargetID = n;
.
.
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in blah.GetControl() you are instantiating a control with ID 'a8f08c40d0fab104ca20b1460ee1cbdd1e121'. This control is of a type that has a property TargetControlID like for instance the Accordion control. So you will need to set this TargetControlID to a valid id of a control as well in the GetControl. So set both ID and TargetontrolID.

**update**: you can get the id with the ClientID property. This contains the full ID as it's rendered in the HTML.

Comment: You are absolutely 100% correct thank you!

The problem I have now is that my target control is a div with an ID, and putting the div's ID in doesn't work, presumably because the div's real ID is not the one I set in code, but something like "ct100$MyDivName". Do you know how I can use a div as the target? Before I generated the control dynamically, the target was a div and it worked okay.

Comment: I'm not sure how... Typing the div id and a dot doesnt generate any intellisense because it's not an asp control.

Comment: Was missing a runat=server from my div...

The TargetControlID of 'aab822f2d0cace04' is not valid. A control with ID 'ctl00_MainContentPlaceHolder_divDetailsContent' could not be found.

ClientID doesn't seem to work though.